# GIT: Не вижу коммит после того как переключился на другую ветку

Tags: git, commit

1. В ветке features все пошло не так, легче было откатиться назад
2. Я переключился на предыдущий коммит с  get checkout sdf2fasdq2 (хеш коммита)
3. Сделал изменения, закоммитил но запушить не смог, решил что сначала нужно переключиться обратно на features
4. Переключившись все пропало, мое коммита как не было.
   git branch, git log - не видят ни как ветку мой коммит, ни вообще в истории

Что я сделал не так?
Я могу что ни будь сделать?

Comment: Пункт 2 не был «откатом назад». И гит об этом пишет большое предупреждение, но кто ж их читает

Comment: *"Что я сделал не так"* - начал использовать git вместо hg :D. Ну а вообще видимо тут характерная ситуация, когда на один или несколько коммитов не ведет ни одна цепочка ссылок (от ветки или head) и он получается недостижим. В этом случае обычно можно попробовать сразу выполнить `git reflog` и посмотреть, нет ли коммита в списке, а затем по ситуации.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но на шаге 2 не мог пропасть коммит, сделанный на шаге 3...

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, он «пропал» на шаге 4. Потому то шаг 2 был не «откат назад», а переход в detached head режим.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а понял. Он не на ветку перешёл... А разве в detached head вообще коммитить что-то можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy коммитить можно без проблем. Просто это будут коммиты не прикреплённые ни к какой ветке.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, хм.. никогда так не делал, всегда сначала создавал ветку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускаем `git reflog`

Находим и запоминаем хэш коммита

Переключаемся на ветку features (если мы ещё не там)

Пишем `git reset --hard хэш-запомненного-коммита`